# min max number in text input - Jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, numbers, range

I would like to set a minimum and maximum allowed number to be entered in text input I know I can do this with range input but will it still have the max and min when used in non compatible browsers?

if not could you please point me in the right direction, thanks for reading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [jquery validator plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/). It has a nice set of features, and min max validation too. But checking values on server side is a must too. [Here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods) is an examples for [min](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/min#value) and [max](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/max#value).

Answer (score 0):

No; you can never rely on the client. Always check on the server side as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've had success with the jQuery [h5Validate](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/h5Validate) plugin.  Its pretty simple in what it aims to accomplish (which is exactly what you want here).

Also, validate it on the server side too.