# JavaScript to accept only numbers between 0 to 255 range

Tags: javascript

My Requirement is to validate the ip ranges, I need to create a JavaScript function to accept only numeric and it must allow only between the range 0 to 255. If anything is entered beyond that it must alert a message.

I am currently using this below function

```
<script language="JavaScript"> 

function allownums(a) 
{ 

if(a <48 ||a > 57) 
alert("invalid") 
else 
alert("vaild") 
} 

</script> 
<input type='text' id='numonly' onkeypress='allownums(event.keycode)'>
```

I am new to JavaScript, Need some experts suggestion to fix my requirement. Please suggest me

Thanks
Sudhir

Comment: It appears you're validating the key being pressed. I believe you need to validate the value of the input field.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858949/min-max-number-in-text-input-jquery-javascript

Comment: @JamWaffles: Javascript is the kind of language/system you learn this way; copy, paste, adapt. It is so ubiquitous and so immediate that it will be the first language for a great many people, and they will do it incrementally, an if statement here and a `window.alert('oh noes')` there. That may sound like a bad thing, but it actually just adds a whole raft of potential programmers for whom the learning curve was too steep before, or the barrier to entry too high.

Comment: @Phil Yes, but instead of asking "How do I do this" on SO for every thing the learner gets stuck on, they should try to learn from other resources that are designed for learning from, not solving a problem. I've seen a [certain user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/376947/alex) do the former a lot.

Comment: @JamWaffles: True. Interesting profile for that user, the questions they ask seem to get a lot of upvotes, so perhaps they are doing a good job of asking questions that others find in their own search. It does seem like a rather skewed balance, though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you have the test

```
(a < 48) || (a > 57)
```

for invalid values. So I would change those:

```
(a < 0 ) || (a > 255)
```

You may also need to consider what you'll do with non-integral input like 2.3 - either round it or treat it as invalid.

At present, as Kelvin Mackay points out, you are performing the validation on the keypress event rather than the input value, so change the onkeypress to `allownums(this.value)`.

I would advise changing the alert to a warning in a div, and using the validation to enable/disable a submit button, as popups are quite annoying in just about every circumstance.

To clear the input when an invalid entry is made (as requested in a comment) would make it rather annoying for the user; as soon as a key is pressed to add a digit and make the input invalid, the whole input is cleared. The code, however, would be:

```
if(!validnum(this.value)) 
    this.value="";
```

in the input tag, thus:

```
<input type='text' id='numonly' 
      onkeyup='if(!validnum(this.value)) this.value="";'>
```

with the function changed to:

```
function validnum(a) { 
    if(a < 0 || a > 255) 
        return false;
    else 
        return true;
}
```

or more succinctly:

```
function validnum(a) {
    return ((a >= 0) && (a <= 255));
}
```

Edit: To alert and clear the box, if you must:

```
function validOrPunchTheUser(inputElement) {
    if(!validnum(inputElement.value)) {
        window.alert('badness'); // punch the user
        inputElement.value = ""; // take away their things
    }
}

<input type='text' id='numonly' 
      onkeyup='validOrPunchTheUser(this)'>
```

However, reading other answers, apparently you are looking to validate an octet (e.g. in an IP address). If so, please state that in the question, as it passed me by today. For an octet:

```
function validateIPKeyPress(event) {
    var key = event.keyCode;
    var currentvalue = event.target.value;
    if(key < 96 || key > 105)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        window.alert('pain');
        return false;
    }
    else if(currentvalue.length > 2 ||
            (currentvalue.length == 2 &&
             key > 101)) {
        window.alert('of death');
        event.preventDefault();
        event.target.value = event.target.value.substring(0,2);
    }
    else
        return true;
}
```

With the input tag:

```
<input type='text' id='octet'
          onkeydown='validateIPKeyPress(event)'>
```

Except please don't use alerts. If you take out the alert lines, it will silently prevent invalid inputs. Note the change to use onkeydown now, so that we can catch invalid key presses and prevent the value changing at all. If you must clear the input, then do `if(!validateIPKeyPress(event)) this.value = "";`.

Comment: This function work good now if(a < 0 || a > 255) but can we clear the box when invalid is alereted?

Comment: I've updated the question to answer that, but as I explain, please don't do that to real users. Alerts are annoying, and so are scripts that throw away your input. Using both will be rude.

Comment: Your function clears the item value on the fourth digit is entered. As soon 256 is entered it must alert and clear the box, This is my requirement  Please suggest me. input box must not take characters and special symbols

Comment: Thanks, I realised that I was using keypress (which triggers before the value has changed) instead of keyup which triggers afterwards. I've changed the html. I've also added an octet validation function, which seems more what you are looking for, though you don't state it in the question!

Answer (score 1):

I would rather go instantly for validation of whole ip address. Allowing input both numbers and dots, parsing them thru REGEX pattern.

Pattern usage example you could fetch here:
http://www.darian-brown.com/validate-ip-addresses-javascript-and-php-example/

The code itself would look something like:

```html
<input type='text' id='numonly' value="" onkeypress='allowIp(event)' onkeyup='javascript:checkIp()'>
```

```js
function allowIp(e){
if((e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57) && e.keyCode != 46)  // both nubmer range and period allowed, otherwise prevent.
  { 
      e.preventDefault();
  }
}

function checkIp() 
{ 
  var ip = $("#numonly").val();

    /* The regular expression pattern */
  var pattern = new RegExp("^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.)(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.)(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.)([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$");

  /* use  javascript's test() function to execute the regular expression and then store the result - which is either true or false */
  var bValidIP = pattern.test(ip);

  if(bValidIP){
     // IP has ok pattern
     $("#numonly").css("background", "green");
  }
  else {
     $("#numonly").css("background", "red");
  }
}
```

You could check it here on fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Indias/P3Uwg/

Answer (score 1):

#### Single Integer

You can use the following solution to check if the user input for a **single integer** is between 0 - 255:

```js
document.getElementById('example').addEventListener('input', event => {
  const input = event.target.value;
  console.log(/^\d+$/.test(input) && input > -1 && input < 256);
});
```

```html
<input id="example" type="text" placeholder="Enter single integer" />
```

---

#### IP Address

Alternatively, you can use the code below to verify that each section of an **IP address** is between 0 - 255:

```js
document.getElementById('example').addEventListener('input', event => {
  const input = event.target.value;
  console.log(input === new Uint8ClampedArray(input.split('.')).join('.'));
});
```

```html
<input id="example" type="text" placeholder="Enter IP address" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to validate the current value of the input, rather than the last key that was pressed:

```
<input type='text' id='numonly' onkeypress='allownums(this.value)'>
```

Your function then just needs to be modified to: `if(a < 0 || a > 255)`

Comment: This function works good now with condition if(a < 0 || a > 255). But it is allow to accept 000 and it must accept only numbers.

Answer (score 0):

A function like this should do it:

```
function allownums(value){
   var num = parseInt(value,10);
   if(num <0 || num>255)
      alert('invalid')      
}
```

Then have your html look like:

```
<input type='text' id='numonly' onblur='allownums(this.value)'>
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/USL3E/

Answer (score 0):

*Update*
I've set up [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/USL3E/1/) that does some basic IP-formatting and checks weather or not all input is in range (0 - 255) etc... feel free to use it, improve it, study it... I've also updated the code snippet here to match the fiddle

There are several things you're not taking into account. First and foremost is that *not all browsers have a `keycode` property set on the event objects*. You're better off passing the entire event object to the function, and deal with X-browser issues there. 
Secondly, you're checking key after key, but at no point are you checking the *actual* value that your input field is getting. There are a few more things, like the use of the `onkeypress` html attribute (which I don't really like to see used), and the undefined return value, but that would take us a little too far... here's what I suggest - HTML:

```
<input type='text' id='numonly' onkeypress='allowNums(event)'>
```

JS:

```
function allowNums(e)
{
    var key = e.keycode || e.which;//X-browser
    var allow = '.0123456789';//string the allowed chars:
    var matches,element = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if (String.fromCharCode(key).length === 0)
    {
        return e;
    }
    if (allow.indexOf(String.fromCharCode(key)) === 0)
    {//dot
        element.value = element.value.replace(/[0-9]+$/,function(group)
        {
            return ('000' + group).substr(-3);
        });
        return e;
    }
    if (allow.indexOf(String.fromCharCode(key)) > -1)
    {
        matches = (element.value.replace(/\./g) + String.fromCharCode(key)).match(/[0-9]{1,3}/g);
        if (+(matches[matches.length -1]) <= 255)
        {
            element.value = matches.join('.');
        }
    }
    e.returnValue = false;
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    if (e.preventDefault)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
}​
```

Now this code still needs *a lot* of work, this is just to get you going, and hopefully encourage you to look into the *event object*, how JS event handlers work and all the rest. BTW, since you're new to JS, [this site is worth a bookmark](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html)

Comment: Wait, what? You're only allowing chars `012345`? In an IP address? IP address parts can have characters 0-9

Comment: @Jamiec: Oops, overlooked that the question dealt with ip's... I misread that... I'll edit in a moment

Answer (score 0):

```
    function fun_key()
    {
    var key=event.keyCode;
    if(key>=48 && key<=57)
    {
    return true;
    }
    else
    {
    return false;
    alert("please enter only number");
    }
    }

    and you can call this function on keypress event like:
    <asp:textbox id="txtphonenumber" runat="server" onkeypress="return fun_key()">                </asp"textbox>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen many answers that have overlooked two important factors that may fail to validate range number on keypress:

1. **When the value in input textbox is NOT SELECTED**, the real outcome should be `(input.value * 10) + parseInt(e.key)` and not simply `input.value + parseInt(e.key)`. It should be `* 10` because you add one more digit at the back during keypress, e.g. `10` becomes `109`.
2. **When the value in input textbox IS SELECTED**, you can simply check if `Number.isInteger(parseInt(e.key))` because when `255` is selected, pressing `9` will not turn into `2559` but `9` instead.

So first of all, write a simple function that check if the input value is selected by the user:

```
function isTextSelected (input) {
    if (!input instanceof HTMLInputElement) {
        throw new Error("Invalid argument type: 'input'. Object type must be HTMLInputElement.");
    };
    return document.getSelection().toString() != "" && input === document.activeElement;
}
```

Next, this will be your on keypress event handler that takes into consideration of the above two factors:

```
$("input[type='number']").on("keypress", function (e) {
     if (!Number.isInteger(parseInt(e.key)) || (($(this).val() * 10) + parseInt(e.key) > 255 
         && !isTextSelected($(this)[0]))) {
         e.preventDefault();
     };
});
```

Take note of this condition within another brackets, it is one whole condition by itself:

`(($(this).val() * 10) + parseInt(e.key) > 255 && !isTextSelected($(this)[0]))`

For the `< 0` condition, you don't even need it here because the negative sign `(-)` will be automatically prevented as the sign itself is **not an integer**.

**KNOWN ISSUE:** The above solution, however, does not solve the situation when the user move the cursor to the **start position** of `29` and press `1`, which will become `129`. This is because `29 * 10 = 290`, which already exceed `255`, preventing user from entering `129`, which is valid. The **start position** is particularly hard to track when the input `type="number"`. But it should be enough to resolve the normal way of input for an integer range field. Any other better solutions are welcome.