# enter 0 to 100 in text field using jquery regex

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to enter 0.00 to 100.00 in text field using jquery regular expression. I am new for regex. Please help me how can I do this?
I do not allow to enter more than 100.00 or negative values.

```js
var regex = "^\$(\d{1,3},?(\d{3},?)*\d{3}(\.\d{1,3})?|\d{1,3}(\.\d{2})?)$|^\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})? *%$|^100%$";
```

```html
<input type="text" class="count">
```

How can I use this regex in textbox. I just want t allow only two numbers after decimal. Example (0.00 and 100.00 or 99.99) like this.

Comment: why do you want to use regex here?

Comment: Very less code. And Without regex how can I do? I want all the conditions what I have mention.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413320/javascript-to-accept-only-numbers-between-0-to-255-range

Comment: This should not be solved by using regex, look at madalin ivascu's answer which is much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

For modern browser is sugest the input type number

```html
<form>
<input type="number" class="count" min="0.00" max="100" step="0.01">
<input type="submit"></form>
```

Comment: I want to do as input type "text" And need to use jquery regex.

Comment: doesn't this satisfy you conditions?

Comment: Sorry, I want to use regex. I tried this. But its not working. It is allowing more than 100 also.

Comment: provide a printscreen of allowed value grater then 100 on this code and i will provide you with a regex

Comment: I checked this in fiddle. It is allowing n number of values and n number of decimal symbol. Its like(545545........454....7575....46547575) like this.

Comment: The input is considered invalid when that kind of input is entered. This answer is correct imo.