# validate input with a number range with on keypress event Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following situation.I have an input and I need that as I write I validate that the value of that input is between 1 and 100. The function cannot allow to write a number greater than 100. In my code I get that validation done but it only works when I write the fourth character, then it does not let me write anything else, I need that if I have 2 characters in the input, I will not be allowed to write a third because the number would be greater than 100, I should only write a third character if the written numbers are 1 and 0, that is 10.

```
<input type="text" class="porciento" name="">
```

```
$(document.body).on("keypress", ".porciento", function (event) {

        var numero=$(this).val();
         if($(this).val()>100){     
             event.preventDefault();            
         }
    });
```

Comment: `<input type="number" min="1" max="100" required />`

Comment: If I type the number with the keyboard in the input that does not work

Comment: `if (+$(this).val()>100) this.value=100`

Comment: @epascarello the problem with that (and I've seen it in many sites) is that you'll see a glitch each time the input value has to be corrected to 100. I mean, value will be printed and then corrected. To avoid that you have to prevent the event on keydown.

Comment: I never understand why people are doing those things, what will happen in a case where a user will highlight `100` and try to input another value? They will have to first delete the old one and only then they'll be able to input the other number! Just use a normal validation

Comment: @ErnestoStifano oh I know, it kills usability on multiple levels. So much easier to just validate

Comment: @AlonEitan I know what you are saying but the application I am doing has other inputs that are calculated from the number that is written in that input, therefore I need in this case to behave that way

Comment: @AlonEitan I agree with you that this things must be done carefully. But that case and many other (copy, paste, form auto-completion, etc) can be taken into account to create a decent implementation. It is not easy, but it surely can be done. Many standard cool UX features that we see this days are just hackish solutions. Developers are always doing things for what web standards are not prepared for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go... you may personalize it as you want, but this is the logic.

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    const val = parseInt(e.target.value + e.key);
    if (!isNaN(val) && val > 100) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}, {passive: false, capture: true});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="myInput">
```

Comment: And try and type `67f`

Comment: @epascarello as I said, this is the basic logic. I've just answered a specific question. A decent form library has thousands of code lines. It depends on what OP wants to do.

Comment: @JesúsSotoMitjans please note that I used `.getElementsByTagName()`, it looks for html tags ('input', 'div', 'span', etc) and always returns an array. Use any other method you want to get your input and attach the event handler.

Comment: I have another validation so that it does not allow to write letters or special characters. That code solved the range problem.Thanks @ErnestoStifano

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document.body).on("keypress", ".porciento", function (event) {

    var numero=$(this).val();
     if($(this).val()>100){     
         event.preventDefault();            
     }
});

<input type="text" class="porciento" name="">
```

Comment: If you [edit] your answer and add an explanation as to how your code answers the question, it will make your answer much more valuable to others and more likely to be upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Two important factors to consider when performing range number validation during keypress;

1. **When the value in input textbox is NOT SELECTED**, the real outcome should be `(input.value * 10) + parseInt(e.key)` and not simply `input.value + parseInt(e.key)`. It should be `* 10` because you add one more digit at the back during keypress, e.g. `10` becomes `109`.
2. **When the value in input textbox IS SELECTED**, you can simply check if `Number.isInteger(parseInt(e.key))` because when `100` is selected, pressing `9` will not turn into `1009` but `9` instead.

You can checkout [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63358265/2200913) for further explanation and change a little bit of the code to suit your need.