# Set a max value to a text box in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a text box in the form which should allow only numeric values that is less than the boundary value 2147483647 (max value of Int32)? Can anybody help me in doing this with JQuery? 
I have tried using by adding a validate plugin in eclipse but it is not working. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show us code? something you tried? We can help you, don't solve the problem for you.

Comment: You should read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4859025/2190252) posted on another question.

Comment: Do you want only positive integers less than 2147483647?

Comment: did any answer helped you?!

Answer (score 2):

here sample code:

```
$('#textboxID').on('change',function(){
    if($(this).val()>=2147483647){
    //put error span with nice css
    }
    });
```

Comment: Deleted my answer and upvoted this instead. Turns out you can type anything into an `<input type="number">`, regardless of the value of the `max` attribute (at least in current Chrome). So, my solution might be interesting, but it is not very useful in practice.

Comment: @bfavaretto "that is less than the boundary value 2147483647"... this answer will accept `2147483647`, which is invalid.

Comment: @MuhammadRamahy, It also doesn't address the only numeric values part however... =P

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="numberField"  />
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"  />
```

JQuery:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
    var numberField = $('#numberField');
    var number = parseInt(numberField.val(), 10);
    if(isNaN(number) || number > 2147483647){
        numberField.val('');
        alert('Not a number');
    }
    else
        alert('Number is: '+ number);
});
```

jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/R3Rx2/1/

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/mSSYT/1/**

```
$('#test').on('keyup', function (e) {
    var $self = $(this),
        v = $self.val(),
        max = 2147483647;

    //blank any input that isint a number
    if (!/^\d*$/.test(v)) {
        $self.val('');
        return;
    }

    //trim the value until it meets the condition
    if (v >= max) { 
        while (v >= max) {
            v = v.substring(0, v.length - 1);
        }

        $self.val(v);
    }
});
```